# transsparency issue with PNG images

Tags: compact-framework, png, transparency

I need to display PNG images with transparent background.

in OpennetCF.Button2:

```
        btn.ImageList = ilIcons;
        btn.ImageIndex = (int)ImageIndex;
```

and PictureBox

```
        pbMyPB.Image = (Image)_ResourceManager.GetObject("MyImage");
```

Some images are displayed correctly, but some images are shown with black background.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What's the difference between the "working" and "not working" images?

Comment: It's worth mentioning, now that you have asked 20 questions here on SO, that you're likely to get far more useful answers a lot faster if you improve your questions a bit.  This is very worthwhile reading to help you improve: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: correctly shown - transparent background, incorrectly - black background!

Comment: As I mentioned, this is .NET CF issue/bug. I need book ".NET Compact Frameworks Bugs and Workarounds".

Comment: Is this a solution? http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2010/07/23/KeepingABitmapsTransparencyWhenCopying.aspx

Comment: I mean what's the difference in the images themselves?  Different color depth?  Different image format, color depth, alpha level?  Does one that works always work, or is it a "smethimes it works, sometimes it doesn't" thing?  I assume you're trying to use alpha transparency, not colorcode transparency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your images, do they all share a similar background color?

For instance, all of my images have a White or semi-transparent background and go onto a White canvas:

[image: Resources Screen]

So, if your image is going onto a Button, you might need to try to find or create some images that match your Button's color or change your Button color to match up with the background colors of your items.

Hope this helps.

Joe

Comment: OK, solution: do not use PNGs with transparent background

Comment: Finding good pictures makes a big difference in how a two bit application is received, though. :)